# Leer archivos txt y graficarlos en matlab, pero me señala: Error using load Unable to read file 'tiempo.txt': no such file or directory

Tags: matlab, txt

Ambos textos contienen 1000 datos, la variable  t son los valores desde el 0.05 al 50 con aumentos de 0.05 y la variable s1 son los valores de t^3.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar que el archivo está en el current folder. Si está y sigue habiendo problemas siendo ese tipo de datos yo lo pasaría a excel que permite importarlo manualmente que para las primeras veces que se importa es más claro

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer], ya que tú respuesta, puede ser reportada como de baja calidad.